# Inject the mock object where an actual implementation

Tags: java, junit, mocking, easymock, inject

I want to know what does this code mean:

```
mathApplication.setCalculatorService(calcService);
```

Why should I use an interface and make object from it? And what does this injection means?

Here is my Tester Code:

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.EasyMockRunner;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class MathApplicationTester {

    private MathApplication mathApplication;
    private CalculatorService calcService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mathApplication = new MathApplication();
        calcService = EasyMock.createMock(CalculatorService.class);
        mathApplication.setCalculatorService(calcService);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddAndSubtract() {

        //add the behavior to add numbers
        EasyMock.expect(calcService.add(20.0, 10.0)).andReturn(30.0);

        //subtract the behavior to subtract numbers
        EasyMock.expect(calcService.subtract(20.0, 10.0)).andReturn(10.0);

        //activate the mock
        EasyMock.replay(calcService);

        //test the subtract functionality
        Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.subtract(20.0, 10.0), 10.0, 0);

        //test the add functionality
        Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.add(20.0, 10.0), 30.0, 0);

        //verify call to calcService is made or not
        EasyMock.verify(calcService);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is called Dependency Injection & is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MathApplication` is **dependent** on a `CalculatorService` which provides - as its name suggests - service for calculations.

However, in **unit tests**, you want to test only the class under test (`MathApplication`), so you want to **replace all the dependencies** by **your own implementation** over which you have full control. For this purpose you use the mock.

```
calcService = EasyMock.createMock(CalculatorService.class);
```

**Dependency injection** is a pattern which "injects" the object you are dependent on into the main object.

There are three approaches to getting instances of objects you class depends on.

```
public class MathApplication {
    // I need an instance of CalculatorService inside the code of MathApplication
    ...
}
```

1: Instantiate the object inside the code of `MathApplication` (it doesn't matter if the `calculatorService` is local or a class attribute). This is not very recommendable way.

```
public double subtract(double a, double b) {
    CalculatorService calculatorService = new SomeFastCalculatorService();
    return calculatorService.subtract(a, b);
}
```

2: Delegate the task of instantiation to an external provider, called *factory*:

```
public double subtract(double a, double b) {
    CalculatorService calculatorService = CalculatorServiceFactory.getInstance();
    return calculatorService.subtract(a, b);
}
```

3: Let someone from outside inject the instance by providing an injection point, either via constructor of via a setter method.

It is used in general for building the "dependency tree" of you whole application (usually using frameworks such as [Spring Dependency Injection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm) or [JavaEE CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html)). Here it used to inject your mock object into the class under test:

```
mathApplication.setCalculatorService(calcService);
```

Later on, in your `@Test` method, you exactly set the behaviour of your mock object.

```
EasyMock.expect(calcService.add(20.0, 10.0)).andReturn(30.0);
```

to be read as "when `calcService.add()` is called with 20 and 10, give 30".

And at the end you:

1. Test if your tested method returns what is expected - `assertXXX()`
2. Test if the calcService has been used - `verify()`

Btw, the code

```
Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.subtract(20.0, 10.0), 10.0, 0);
```

contains an error - look at the [documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29). Correctly it should be

```
Assert.assertEquals(10.0, mathApplication.subtract(20.0, 10.0), 0);
```

It works almost the same, just you will get more proper error message if the test doesn't work:

```
Assertion error - expected 10.0, but was 11.0.
```

And anyway, it would be better readable if written as:

```
double expected = 30.0;
double actual = mathApplication.subtract(20.0, 10.0);
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, 0.0000000001); // never expect exact floating point result
```

And why you should interface: it's a good practice :) It's easier for the frameworks to mock an interface than a class (and some mock frameworks even *cannot* mock a class). And it leads you in learning to separate an interface from its implementation and write better testable classes.

Comment: really helpful man. i know what the code is. i just cant figure the injection part's out :\ . why we do that?

Comment: So now you get it? :) Btw, read also about the proper usage of assert().

Comment: i read about assert an other stuff in my code. but the injection, noo :(
can you help me more?

Comment: @Hamid Please see the two links in my answer: Spring Dependency Injection and JavaEE CDI. You may also search for more detailed explanation of dependency injection. I added some more explanation but for more you should use external sources.